# Persistent Clipboard

Tags: clipboard

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS whenever I copy some data from a file and close it, it is not available for pasting into another document. I have to keep the source file open until I paste the data into destination file.
Any way I can make my clipboard persistent..? 
Because in Windows 8 the clipboard handles your data even if the source file is closed.

Comment: How do you Copy&Paste? Select&Middleclick or Ctrl+C&Ctrl+V?

Comment: Ctrl+c , ctrl+v

Comment: just came across this one

Comment: Clipboard Indicator tweak
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286653/gnome-extensions-disabled-after-upgrading-to-20-10
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/
though I have not used it myself, I use parcellite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Diodon clipboard manage using the below commands :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diodon-team/stable`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install diodon unity-scope-diodon`

Starting from 16.04 and up yoy only need to run the last command.

Plugins package is to show an indicator icon in Ubuntu. Start Diodon from the menu/launcher or logout to start at next log-in.

Comment: For adding shortcut for Diodon Clipboard History

In Ubuntu:
Settings>Keyboard>Keyboard Shortcuts>View and Customize Shortcuts>Custom Shortcuts>”+”

My setting “Set Custom Shortcut”

Name: ️ Diodon Clipboard History
Command: /usr/bin/diodon
Shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+V

Answer (score 1):

For people who have the same problem,
I suggest `CopyQ`.
It keeps all the clipboard saved even the images and etc.

```bash
sudo apt-get install copyq
```

If you want, you can set a shortcut from the Settings->Keyboard;
for shortcut command you should write `copyq menu` and any key that you want.